# Python - socket.recvfrom() get entire IP/UDP packet?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, ipv6

Is there a way to use `socket.recvfrom(buf)` to get all IP and UPD data?
specifically, I want to know the udp header (source port, dest port, length, application data) as well as the ip specifics : what ip did it come from, what address was it sent to?

Snippet:

```
addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo(MULTICAST_ADDR, None)[0]
sock = socket.socket(addrinfo[0], socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('', DEST_PORT))

#Join Multicast grp.
group = socket.inet_pton(addrinfo[0], addrinfo[4][0])
mreq = group + struct.pack('@I', 0)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IPV6_JOIN_GROUP, mreq)

while True:
    udp_data,ip_sender = sock.recvfrom(4000)
    #Only returns udp data field and ip of sender
```

Im on windows, and using socket.SOCK_RAW hangs (?) Are there any work-arounds?

Comment: Yes you are right , need use `RAW_SOCKET` .

Comment: The second value returned from `recvfrom` is actually a tuple containing sender's IP address and port (e.g. `('192.168.4.135', 37754)`) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_RAW)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('', DEST_PORT))

sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IPV6, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
```

before joining multicast grp seems to work!